# How do I align a widget to the either right or left depending on a condition

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am building a chat widget and would like the bot response to be on the left and the user response to be on right.

However, although I am identifying the user type correctly both responses are starting from the left

How can I modify the code so that BOT message is position to the left and user message to the right

```
List<Widget> botMessage(context) {
    return <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/rce_icon.jpg'),
              radius: 10.0,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 8.0,
            ),
            Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
              ),
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 5.0),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                child: Text(
                  replies,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }
//should be align right
  List<Widget> userMessage(context) {
    return <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10.0, right: 25.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
              ),
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 16.0),
              child: Text(
                replies,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: this.type ? botMessage(context) : userMessage(context),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `mainAxisAlignment`, inside `Row` Widget `mainAxisAlignment` is used for alignement

```
   Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment:
          this.type ? MainAxisAlignment.start : MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: this.type ? botMessage(context) : userMessage(context),
    ),
```